# python - More efficient way to scrape webpage with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a script to scrape a Wikipedia page with a list of names for those names. Specifically, I am scraping a Wikipedia page with a list of the names of every jazz pianist (according to Wikipedia, at least). **What I want to do is append all of the pianist's names on this page into a list.** Here is the link to the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_jazz_pianists

I managed to reach a solution with Beautiful Soup v4, but it looks very clunky. Let me describe that solution and why I reached it. (I won't include the HTML file in this post for brevity's sake)

```python
import requests
import bs4

result = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_jazz_pianists")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
bigList = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'div-col columns column-width'})
```

bigList is the list of each div class = div-col columns column-width, because these divs contain
the actual names of the artists.

```python
artistList = []
index = 0
for nameTag in bigList[5].contents[1].contents:
    if index % 2 == 0:
        artistList.append(nameTag.contents[0].contents[0])
        
    index += 1
    
print(artistList)
```

This is going to take some explaining. It will help if you look at the HTML file for the Wikipedia page. `bigList[5]` gives all last names of 'F', as F is the 6th character in the alphabet. `bigList[5].contents` gives a list of 3 elements: a newline escape character, the entire `<li>` list for F, and finally another
newline escape character. So `bigList[5].contents[1]` accesses the entire `<li>` list for F.
`bigList[5].contents[1].contents` gives a list of each `<li>` element, separated by a newline escape
character. So my thinking was that I would iterate through each element in this list, only taking the even-indexed elements, as the odd-indexed elements were all newline escape characters. `nameTag.contents` gives a list consisting of two elements, the hyperlink and name for the pianist, and their date of birth - date of death. So I select the first element of that list. Finally, `nameTag.contents[0].contents` gives a list containing only one element, the name of the pianist, so I pull the only element of this list in order to append it to artistList as a string, and not a nested list.

As you can see, this is an extremely complicated process for something that seems like it should be simpler. Given that I am new to bs4 and web scraping with python in general, I feel like there's a better solution to this. Moreover, I eventually want to collect data from each pianist's page that is linked on this page. My solution is not very robust or efficient, and I know that will give me problems moving forward with this project.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I really appreciate the help, and I'm sorry for the length of the post and any other inappropriate or non-idiomatic mistakes - I am new to stack overflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution maybe relies a bit too much on formatting of the page, although scraping WikiPedia will always be hard because the elements with the data are not marked with identifiers or classes indicating what data they hold, so you're stuck with relying on the structure of the tables remaining the same anyway.

You find the right data, but really all that sets the artist links apart is that they are the `<a>` elements inside `div-col` `<div>` elements.

A simpler solution with BS4 (considering you're after both the artist name and a link to their page):

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_jazz_pianists") as response:
    bs = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
    for div_col in bs.find_all('div', {'class': 'div-col'}):
        for artist_tag in div_col.find_all('a'):
            print(f'{artist_tag.text}, {artist_tag.attrs["href"]}')
```

Note this doesn't use the third party `requests`, but the standard `urllib`.

Result:

```
Irving Aaronson, /wiki/Irving_Aaronson
Anders Aarum, /wiki/Anders_Aarum
...
Bojan Zulfikarpašić, /wiki/Bojan_Zulfikarpa%C5%A1i%C4%87
Axel Zwingenberger, /wiki/Axel_Zwingenberger
```

If you're all about efficiency (or rather briefness), this one-liner may be what you like:

```
result = [(a.text, a.attrs['href'])
          for d in bs.find_all('div', {'class': 'div-col'})
          for a in d.find_all('a')]
```

`result` will be a list of tuples of artist name and link, i.e. `[('Irving Aaronson', '/wiki/Irving_Aaronson'), ('Anders Aarum', '/wiki/Anders_Aarum'), ..]`

Answer (score 1):

After finding `bigList`, you could use this line to replace the rest of the lines :

```
[row['title'] for row in bigList[5].find_all('a')]
```

To understand this code, view outputs of `bigList[5]`, bigList[5].find_all('a')` and then try the line as well.

You could similarly use `href` in place of `title` to find the urls.